# How to shuffle a ImmutableJS List

Tags: immutable.js

What is an performant implementation of [lodash's shuffle function](https://lodash.com/docs#shuffle) ( or similar) to shuffle an Immutable List without using from/toJs()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -
`list = list.sortBy(Math.random)`

This is very crude, but explains the idea which is to re-position items with a certain degree of randomness. Now you should be able to provider different comparator implementation instead of the plain vanilla random to influence a shuffle flavor.

Comment: This isn't just "crude"—it's outright biased (thus arguably incorrect). https://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/#shuffling explains that sort comparisons must be transitive and shows why this is a poor choice for randomness. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/ among others show the bias as well.

Comment: Yes, the disclaimers are all there in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I used the random-js shuffle function.

```
import Random from 'random-js';

let shuffled = (Random().shuffle(list.toArray()));
```